# How to maintain the proper workflow using Git, Bitbucket and Heroku?

Tags: git, heroku, continuous-integration, bitbucket, workflow

I have a webapp project and I keep its sourcecode on bitbucket (git). So I host the app itself on Heroku. Firstly everything went smooth but not proper. Now when I realize that the structure was wrong and should be changed I can't figure out how to cope with in on Heroku.

I'm talking about the proper workflow - to have a master branch and at least one more additional branch for development and testing. 
I also found [this article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments) describing how developers can organize 2 apps - one is staging, and one is production. BUT I still don't understand how it can be done if I use the same local folder to push to bitbucket. As far as I know it's not possible to use the same local folder for different repositories. Also, as far as I know, Heroku can't be used as a normal remote repository - they are hosting company, and even don't have all the tools to do version control.

How would you solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku can totally work with that master/dev git workflow. Heroku acts as a git remote so you can push (i.e. deploy) code to whichever Heroku app (i.e. git remote) you wish.

You will need a production, staging Heroku apps (in git terms, 2 git remotes, let's call them `prod` and `qa` + the existing remote pointing at bitbucket `origin`)

When creating a new app via heroku cli, you can define the git remote name:

```
heroku create --remote qa
```

You can also use git to rename remotes:
    git remote rename heroku heroku-staging

**Take the time to read more from Heroku's documentation** [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments)
*I'd also suggest reading more about git remotes to better understand how it all works.*

Comment: Thanks but I want to keep all my files in bitbucket. I also want to use Heroku only as hosting not for keeping my files. Those it turned out I have to use the same local folder for 2 different repos what is kind of impossible. Or possible?

Comment: I saw the article you gave, I just forgot to add the link to the question. It's still not clear how to use bitbucket for source control and heroku for hosting.

Comment: Heroku can't be used for anything except hosting, so don't worry :)

Comment: and Bitbucket will remain your online git repo that has backups of your code

Comment: from the heroku doc: "Before you can deploy your app to Heroku, you need to initialize a local Git repository and commit your application code to it" ---- So again, how is it possible to have the same folder initialized for 2 different remote repos - one for bitbucket and second for Heroku?

Comment: I understand, you can do `git remote add bitbucket git@bitbucket.org:XXXXX/YYYYYY.git` and also you can list all the git remotes attached to your local folder by running `git remote -v` Heroku git remotes are actually used solely for deployments, so don't get confused seeing them listed as a git remote. Let me know if this does or doesn't answer your question.

Comment: thanks a lot! What is still confusing me is what exactly should I do now. I have app on heroku with git repo, and 2 branches on bitbucket - master and dev. I would like to connect dev to another app(?branch?) on heroku that is not existing yet, how? thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154728/discussion-between-mostafazh-and-mimic).